# Javascript array object compare to get unlisted array result

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays object below:

1. var data: The complete data
2. var choose: The only choose

```js
var data = [
    {
        "day": "Mon",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "day": "Wed",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "day": "Fri",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "day": "Sat",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "day": "Sun",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    }
];

var choose = [
    {
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "day": "Mon",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "day": "Wed",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "day": "Sat",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "day": "Sun",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    }
];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var day = data[i].day;
        var scheduleID = data[i].id;
        var deviceID = data[i].deviceID;
        
        console.log(day);
        
    //How to get Friday array here?
}
```

As We can see above if compare with both array object, I need to get the unlisted result.
So how can I get the array object for Friday only?

Comment: `day` is unique in the data array, or what number of fields are unique per an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array::filter()` to filter your data array and use `Array::some()` in the filter callback to check that the current item's day doesn't exist in the choose array.

It works if `day` is unique per an object in an array, otherwise you should compare several unique fields.

```js
const result = data.filter(item => !choose.some(item2 => item.day === item2.day));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
var data = [
    {
        "day": "Mon",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "day": "Wed",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "day": "Fri",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "day": "Sat",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "day": "Sun",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    }
];

var choose = [
    {
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "day": "Mon",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "day": "Wed",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "day": "Sat",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    },
    {
        "deviceID": "DA0002",
        "id": "SC0001",
        "day": "Sun",
        "time": "08:00",
        "trigger": "ON"
    }
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to filter away all the entries from `choose` from `data`. A basic solution would be to use `Array.filter()`, which runs a function over all items and only keeps the ones where a truthy value was returned:

```
data.filter(datum=>!choose.includes(datum));
```

However, the code above will not work properly here because the data in `data`, while having the same representation in code, will never be equal (i.e. ===) that in `choose` because of how JS handles objects - objects will only be considered "equal" if they are equal by reference:

```
let o1 = {};
let o2 = {};
let o3 = o1;
o1 === o2; // false
o3 === o2; // false
o3 === o1; // true
```

In this case, you will need a deep-equals comparison, which looks at the individual keys and values of objects. A quick hack would be comparing two objects' `JSON.stringify()` representations:

```
data.filter(datum1 =>
  !choose.some(dataum2 => JSON.stringify(datum1) == JSON.stringify(datum2))
);
```

However you can also to look into using libraries, such as `deep-equal`:

```
const deepEqual = require('deep-equal');
data.filter(datum1 => !choose.some(dataum2 => deepEqual(datum1, datum2)));
```

Hope this helps!